# Scrapy only captures one question per page, but there are 10

Tags: python, scrapy

I've been trying to solve this problem for 5 days.
If anyone can help me, thank you:

**Scrapy** only captures one question per page. Each page has 10 questions.

I have already used CSS, xpath + regex, relative address, absolute address, LinkExtractor.

I already disabled obey robots.txt, I already used proxy.

In the scrapy shell, with get() also only captures a question, with get_all() captures all in one.

**My scrapy.py:**

```
import scrapy
from items import GabariteItem


class GbSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "gb"
    start_urls = ['https://www.gabarite.com.br/questoes-de-concursos/assunto/agentes-publicos-e-lei-8112-de-1990']

    def parse(self, response):
        items = response.xpath("//body/div[3]")
        gb = GabariteItem()
        gb['url'] = response.url
        gb['area'] = items.xpath(".//h3/a[2]/text()").extract_first()
        gb['cargo'] = items.xpath(".//h3/a[3]/text()").extract_first()
        gb['curso'] = items.xpath(".//h3/a/text()").extract_first()
        gb['pergunta'] = items.xpath(".//li[@class='pergunta']").extract_first()
        gb['alternativaA'] = items.xpath(".//li[@class='respostas']//label[1]/text()").extract_first()
        gb['alternativaB'] = items.xpath(".//li[@class='respostas']//label[2]/text()").extract_first()
        gb['alternativaC'] = items.xpath(".//li[@class='respostas']//label[3]/text()").extract_first()
        gb['alternativaD'] = items.xpath(".//li[@class='respostas']//label[4]/text()").extract_first()
        gb['alternativaE'] = items.xpath(".//li[@class='respostas']//label[5]/text()").extract_first()
        yield gb

        #Próxima Página
        next_page = response.xpath("//a[@title='Próxima página']/@href").extract_first()
        if next_page:
            # self.log ('Próxima Página: https://www.gabarite.com.br/' + next_page)
            next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse)
```

**My items.py**

```
import scrapy
class GabariteItem(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field()
    area = scrapy.Field()
    cargo = scrapy.Field()
    curso = scrapy.Field()
    ano = scrapy.Field()
    nivel = scrapy.Field()
    pergunta = scrapy.Field()
    alternativaA = scrapy.Field()
    alternativaB = scrapy.Field()
    alternativaC = scrapy.Field()
    alternativaD = scrapy.Field()
    alternativaE = scrapy.Field()
    alternativaCorreta = scrapy.Field()
```

Comment: Why are you searching for div[3]?? just search for article of class "lista-questoes". for example you can do items = response.css('article.lista-questoes') the result will be a list of the 10 questions

Comment: @Fanto. Already had trying article-class "lista-questoes". It continues to result in one question per page. The error is not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over each of the question containers and then select the fields relative to that. Here is an example in scrapy shell:

```
>>> for question in response.css('article.lista-questoes'):
...     print(question.css('.numero h3 ::text').get())
...     # Create item here
... 
Questão 30979.   
Questão 25714.   
Questão 35985.   
Questão 35986.   
Questão 26362.   
Questão 28203.   
Questão 34446.   
Questão 35978.   
Questão 35981.   
Questão 30981.
```

Comment: Thanks! Your observation about the loop helped me find a problem with the yield as well.